# Unable to connect Django Rest framework application with GCP cloud SQL

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework

I created a `could SQL instance` on GCP for `MySql 5.7`. I am trying to connect it with Django Rest framework application. I am also using Docker to containerize Django application. I am running Django application on `localhost` but for MySql I want to use `GCP cloud Sql`.

I got the `public IP address` of the cloud Sql instance once it was up and running. Then I created a database `eitan_database` with user `jeet` and password `root`.

In Django project's `settings.py` file I updated the database settings as following -

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'eitan_database',
        'USER': 'jeet',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '35.239.xxx.x',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

I have used `public IP` for `HOST` and for `PORT` `Mysql` default `3306`.

I don't understand what is wrong with the database configuration but when I run server I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
eitan-application_1  |     self.connect()
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
eitan-application_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
eitan-application_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
eitan-application_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
eitan-application_1  |     return Database.connect(**conn_params)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
eitan-application_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
eitan-application_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
eitan-application_1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.239.117.1' (115)")
```

Comment: have you tried using the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) to connect to the instance? Usually this is an easy way to set up the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `Private IP` of `Cloud SQL` to establish the connection with the  `localhost` which is on different network. To establish the connection with the external network `Public IP's` are used.

Hence, I create a `Public IP` and allowed all the networks to access the Cloud SQL instance.